Failed to fetch Apollo error when trying to useQuery my GraphQL server from docker container to docker container
I have a Next.js app that handle the authentication with NextAuth and request some other data as well.
I also have a GraphQL server that manage the users with a postgre database.
All these services are dockerized and share the same network.
On my Next app, I created the ApolloClient like this :
function createLink(session?: Session | null) {
  const authUrl = "http://node:4000/graphql";
  const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: authUrl,
  });

  const authLink = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
    operation.setContext(({ headers = {} }) => ({
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        ...(session?.accessToken
          ? { Authorization: `Bearer ${session?.accessToken}` }
          : {}),
      },
    }));
    return forward(operation);
  });

  return ApolloLink.from([authLink, httpLink]);
}

const createApolloClient = (session?: Session | null) => {
  return new ApolloClient({
    link: createLink(session),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });
};

In a view, I'm triggering a request like this :
const { data, loading } = useQuery<{ getOccupations: Occupation[] }>(
    getOccupationsDocument,
    {
      variables: {
        skills: params,
      },
      skip: isEmpty(params),
    }
  );

And here is my docker-compose file :
version: "3.8"

services:
  nginx:
    build: ./next/nginx
    container_name: nginx
    networks:
      - postgres-db-network
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - next_app
      - node_app
  next_app:
    build: ./next
    container_name: next
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - postgres-db-network
    volumes:
      - ./next:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app/.next
    depends_on:
      - node_app
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
  node_app:
    build: ./node
    container_name: node
    environment:
      - PGHOST=postgres
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - PORT=4000
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - ./node:/app
      - /app/node_modules
      - /app/dist
      - shared-volume:/app/data
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    networks:
      - postgres-db-network
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: *****
      POSTGRES_USER: *****
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: *****
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - postgres-db-network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -d $${POSTGRES_DB} -U $${POSTGRES_USER}"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
volumes:
  shared-volume:
networks:
  postgres-db-network:
    driver: bridge

Here is the issue : when I authenticate/register myself through NextAuth, it is working like a charm. I guess, since containers shares the same network, they are able to communicate between each others with their container name.
BUT, when I'm triggering the action on the Next app that leads to useQuery to be called, the query is failing with an ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error.
I red a lot of things around how to handle a Next app through Docker. So to make the next app working at the first place, I use the container name in the apollo configuration. Then I reuse the locahost:4000/graphql address but it leads to the app being unable to attach the next auth token to the queries, even though the token is in the session and not being able to handle the getServerSideProps next method as well.
I also handle the cors possible issues with app.use(cors()); on my node.js app.
So as a last try, I create an nginx service in my docker-compose and try to route the /graphql address in the apollo configuration to the localhost one :
location /graphql {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/graphql;
  }

But the app is failing on the initialization and the nginx configuration seems to not being take into account. FYI, I putted these files in the next app folder, at the root level.

The Next app runs in the browser, even if its code is served from a container.  Since it's in the browser it can't use Docker networking features, leading to the ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error.  The easiest solution here is to make sure your Nginx setup proxies both containers, and use a path-only authUrl = '/graphql'.  I have a longer explanation in the linked question.

Hi @DavidMaze, ty for your answer but sorry, I'm not able to make my apps working with your other thread and your repo examples. Your configuration is damn simple but I still get the ApolloError: Failed to parse URL from /graphql error in my next.js app when the getServerSideProps method is triggered. And if I comment this method, I'm getting an 404 because the next app is requesting http://app.test.com:3000/graphql

Don't directly access the port 3000 (maybe even delete all of the ports: except for nginx's).  Invoke your application via the reverse proxy, http://app.test.com/ using the default HTTP port 80.

Hey @DavidMaze, it's me again. I did what you told me, but the login request is failing with a 401 with the request URL http://app.test.com/api/auth/callback/login. const authUrl = "app.test.com:80/graphql"; const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: authUrl, }) on the next app and server { listen 80; server_name localhost; location / { proxy_pass http://next:3000/; }  location /graphql { proxy_pass http://node:4000/graphql; }} on the nginx config

I tried to route the /api endpoint to http://node:4000/graphql as it was specified at the first place in the apollo config but it act weirdly.
